# Parse JSON message within CloudWatch insights log

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Lets say my current query is as follows:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Where my messages consist of valid JSON, such as:

```
{ "timestamp": "2022-06-24T04:03:17,962", "logger": "com.log.LoggerClass", "level": "DEBUG"}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to parse the JSON into discrete fields such that I can do something along the lines of: find all the messages with level: errors and fatals:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message.level like /(?i)error|fatal/ 
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so, vote for it and accept it to help other users

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, time, logger, level
| filter level like /(?i)error|fatal/
| limit 20
| display @message
```

---

For this log file:

```
{ "timestamp": "2022-06-24T04:03:17,962", "logger": "com.log.LoggerClass", "level": "DEBUG"} 
{ "timestamp": "2022-06-24T04:03:18,962", "logger": "com.log.LoggerClass", "level": "ERROR"} 
{ "timestamp": "2022-06-24T04:03:19,962", "logger": "com.log.LoggerClass", "level": "ERROR"} 
{ "timestamp": "2022-06-24T04:03:20,962", "logger": "com.log.LoggerClass", "level": "DEBUG"}
{ "timestamp": "2022-06-24T04:03:21,962", "logger": "com.log.LoggerClass", "level": "ERROR"} 
{ "timestamp": "2022-06-24T04:03:22,962", "logger": "com.log.LoggerClass", "level": "DEBUG"}
{ "timestamp": "2022-06-24T04:03:23,962", "logger": "com.log.LoggerClass", "level": "FATAL"}
```

the output of the query will be:

[image]